# Run a method by onChange with q-select (Quasar Framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, onchange, quasar-framework

The function isn't running when I change the selected value. How do i fix this? Here is my code:

```html
<q-select
  v-model="single"
  :options="['def', 'abc', '456', '123']"
  use-chips
  label="Select One"
  @input="showChannel()"
/>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
methods: {
  showChannel(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Use `@update:model-value` instead of `@input`. (I used **Quasar v2.0.3**)

So, this is your case below:

```js
<q-select
  v-model="single"
  :options="['def', 'abc', '456', '123']"
  use-chips
  label="Select One"
  // @update:model-value instead of @input 
  @update:model-value="showChannel()" 
/>
```

Sometimes, Quasar is tricky.

Answer (score 12):

```
<q-select
  v-model="single"
  :options="['def', 'abc', '456', '123']"
  use-chips
  label="Select One"
  // @update:model-value instead of @input 
  @update:model-value="val => showChannel(val)" 
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who use **Quasar v2**, they changed the event from input to `input-value`

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the events in the documentation. I changed the keyword "change" to "input" and it started working.